# how create many to many and foreign fields together?

Tags: django-models

There is a Model1. In Model 2, I need to make two fields:

```
some_list = models.ManyToManyField (Model1)
some_field = models.ForeignKey (Model1)
```

I see error:

> Reverse accessor for 'Model2.some_field' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Model2.some_list'.

P.S. I do not want to manually create a table "through" and and use only the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two different related names, like this:

```
lead_researcher = models.ForeignKey(related_name='lead_researcher')
participating_researcher = models.ManyToManyField(related_name='participating_researcher')
```